# JQuery callback function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-callback

I'm trying to use callback function of the following type:

```
$('elem').attr(
'attr',
function(i, val){
    return i*10 + 'px';
   }
);
```

to place images one on top of another.

My HTML includes five images only.

**CSS:**

```
img {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('img').attr(
'top',
function(i, val){
    alert(50 + i*110 + 'px');
    return 50 + i*(110) + 'px';
  }
);
```

Alerts in the page: 50px...160px...270px...380px...490px
But images still stuck in one place.
Can you find error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is setting an HTML property, not a CSS property. You image becomes `<img top=50px></img>`, which to the browser means nothing. Use the jquery `.css()` function to manipulate css:

```
$('img').css(
    'top',
    function(i, val){
        return 50 + i*(110) + 'px';
    }
);
```

Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/M6SZE/